# Merging multiple consecutive lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge

I have a vector layer with single-segment lines resulting from exploding a line layer.
I have filtered out some segments and would like to reconnect/merge those remaining segments (sometimes several in a row) for which the respective start/end points overlap.

In QGIS 2.18 I can use the "merge_lines" plugin (https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISMergeLines) which does exactly what I want, but I can't install it on QGIS 3.xx as I get the following error message "Couldn't load plugin 'QGISMergeLines-master' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"

Doing it manually instead is not an option due to the number of lines I deal with.
I also tried using "merge lines" from the processing toolbox but it seems to create an identical copy of my initial layer without merging anything (tried it with several different layers).

Would anybody be able to fix the plugin so its installation works for QGIS 3.xx, or let me know how i could otherwise solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried one of the dissolve tools?

Answer (score 0):

Select the segments you want to merge and click on the `Merge Selected Features` icon in the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar:

[image]

If the toolbar is not visible, open it here: `Menu View > Toolbars > Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`